# CoDrops dropdown onChange event won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm integrating [one](http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/index2.html) of [these dropdown effects](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/) to my project. I want to make a list of countries and when a visitor selects one, it will send him/her to a page. The problem is that onChange() event won't work when **dropdown.js** is in the mix.

I've tried with

```
onChange='this.form.submit()"
```

And with

```
onChange='sendForm()"
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendForm() {
    document.getElementById("destination-select").submit();
}
</script>
```

Both work if I remove dropdown.js, but obviously the effect is lost.

the form is

```
<form id="destination-select" action="/" method="get">
    <select name="destination" id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select" onchange="sendForm()">
         <option value="-1" selected>Destination</option>
         <option value="argentina" class="icon-argentina">Argentina</option>
         <option value="brazil" class="icon-brazil">Brazil</option>
         <option value="spain" class="icon-spain">Spain</option>
         <option value="more " class="icon-more">See more</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

## UPDATE

As [@Amit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2560466/amit) pointed out, there's a onOptionSelect() method, I used it and find, works. The problem is that it doesn't retrieve the selected option. Neither does onChange="sendForm()" nor onChange="this.form.submit()". I even tried to fake a click button with .click() method. Any ideas? Thanks!

a bit of code:

```
<form id="destination-select" action="/" method="get">
    <select name="destination" id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select" >
        <option value="-1" selected disabled>Destination</option>
        <option value="argentina" class="icon-argentina">Argentina</option>
        <option value="brazil" class="icon-brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option value="spain" class="icon-spain">Spain</option>
        <option value="more" class="icon-more">See more</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$( function() {
    $( '#cd-dropdown' ).dropdown({
        gutter : 5,
        delay : 100,
        random : true,
        onOptionSelect: function(opt){
            sendForm();
        }
    });
});
```

sendForm()

```
function sendForm() {
            document.getElementById('destination-select').submit();
        }
```

The result always is: url.dev/?destination=-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have sendForm() function defined before your html. If this doesn't help try this,

The jquery dropdown plugin you are using has a configuration parameter "onOptionSelect".
You can pass a function to this parameter which will receive the selected option as parameter.

```
$("#cd-dropdown").dropdown(
    onOptionSelect: function(opt){
        // you can call your sendForm() here
    }
);
```

Comment: Ok, onOptionSelect works just fine. But, the problem now is that it sets the selected option to "-1". I mean, it doesn't retrieve the selected option but the default option of the dropdown. I've tried: 

`document.getElementById('destination-select').submit();`

into the onOptionSelect. I've also tried calling the sendForm() method, and even faking a submit button click with click(). Everything with the same result: url?destination=-1 //-1 is the default option value

Comment: @JorgeAnzola Check this https://gist.github.com/amitonkare/fcb9e8ea55050f29b1708612d0f2b247
It works and alerts the selected option.

Comment: Genius! That helped me a lot. I still was having some troubles with the form, but now that you tought how to get the countries, I could do something like `window.location.replace("?destination=" + destination);` and it works. I don't know if it's a bad practice or something, but worked. Thanks!